# Element after translation goes back to origin place?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I posted before but there was a lot of code that I changed but the issue is the same. I am trying to translate an element after the mouse moves. here's the code:

```html
<svg id="m" width="40" height="40">
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
    </svg>
    
    <script>
let m = document.getElementById("m");
 
let start = function(e) {
  var speedX = Math.abs(e.movementX);
  var speedY = Math.abs(e.movementY);
  
  m.style.transform = `translate(${speedX}px, ${speedY}px)`;
};
 
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => start(e));
    </script>
```

and I was wondering how to add direction too, but only after fixing this problem. thanks a lot

Comment: What is your actual problem ? Your code does exactly what you told it to do ... Do you maybe mean that the circle always hops back  to its original position ?

Comment: it doesn't translate, it stays in its place "Do you maybe mean that the circle always hops back to its original position ?" -> yes

Comment: Hm, weird, when I try it out it moves very quickly from its original position into the direction of my mouse and then back. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: mozilla firefox

Comment: Have you tried to use `e.offsetX` instead of `e.movementX`? (same for Y axis)

Comment: I tried e.offset for x and y, and it moves very quickly to where my mouse is and go back

Comment: Please tell me the version of your firefox, see [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-what-version-firefox-you-are-using) for information how to find it out.

Comment: 81.0 (64 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are equalizing the position, to the current movement.

What you want is to **add** the movement (not absolute values) to the current position.

Remember: `position = position + velocity`.

You can also improve the behavior, by moving it just when clicking, to avoid it to get out of the screen and making undesired movements.

E.g.:

```js
let m = document.getElementById("m");
let posX = 0;
let posY = 0;

let update = function(e) {
  posX += e.movementX;
  posY += e.movementY;

  m.style.transform = `translate(${posX}px, ${posY}px)`;
};

// Listen to movement when mousedown.
document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", update);
});

// Remove movement when mouseup.
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", update);
});
```

```html
<svg id="m" width="40" height="40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked, but why it didn't work without adding posX and Y?

Comment: It's like real life, if you move at 1km per hour, and you use that speed as your position, you will be always at 1km position. Instead you have a position, and it gets "modified" by the speed.